# Android Application consuming a WebService on a GlassFish server using ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-services, glassfish

I have an android application that consumes a webservice that is located on a GlassFish server on my laptop. When both my laptop and my device is connected to the WiFi, it works as intended. But when I try to access the webservice when my device is connected to the mobile 3g net it throws a timeout error:

> W/System.err(3835): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to >/[RouterIPAddress] (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

I have configurated my router to forward HTTP to my laptops IP and port 8080.

This is my code for calling the WebService:

```
public class WebService {
//Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://service.marcusjacobsson.com/";
//Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
private static String URL = "http://[myRoutersIPAddress]:8080/WebServiceProject/HelloWebService?wsdl";
//SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://service.marcusjacobsson.com/";

public static String[] invokeHelloWorldWS(String webMethName) {
    String[] resultArray = null;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);       
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        if(response!=null){
            int count = response.getPropertyCount();
            resultArray = new String[count];
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                resultArray[i]=response.getProperty(i).toString();
            }
        }
        return resultArray;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Print error
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    //Return resTxt to calling object
    return resultArray;
}   

}
```

What is causing the application to not being able to connect to my laptop over the mobile internet, but it works when both devices are running on the same wifi? (some config is needed with the IP addresses)

Thanks in advance for any answers or tips on how to debug this issue.

Comment: Does your 3G provider allow servers?

Comment: After some research it seems that my provider is blocking direct communication between devices for "security reasons" and that I have to pay up extras to be able to achieve this. Time for a new provider :)